# Understanding newrelic response time

Tags: android, newrelic, apm

I am using newrelic for both api server and android app. When I check performance of an api it shows average response time as 50ms.
But when I check average response time under mobile section for app it shows much greater number(800ms).

So my questions are.

1. What is the meaning of response time in api server, is it time to first byte or time to last byte
2. From where I can find attributes for the difference, is it network or app processing or payload size.
3. How can i get chrome like distribution of an api fired from android app. By Chrome like distribution I meant chrome shows timeline of all network calls with series and parallel invocation and time spent